# Asymptotic analysis: difference between big O and big Omega limits?

Tags: limits, proof-explanation, asymptotics

So I've started university again after taking a break and my first assignment in algorithms is to prove whether $f(n)$ is in Big O / Big Omega of $g(n)$.
These are the limit rules I have:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \infty \Longrightarrow f \in O(g) \\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0 \Longrightarrow f \in o(g) \\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} > 0 \Longrightarrow f \in \Omega(g) \\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \infty \Longrightarrow f \in ω(g)$$

My question is: What is the difference between **Big O** and **Big Omega** in terms of **limits**? Isn't every value bigger than $0$ also smaller than infinity?

Also the following problem:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+\pi}{n-e^{2021}} \text{ with l'Hopital} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$$
So it would be $>0$, so Big Omega, but if I do l'Hopital again, it comes down to zero, meaning small $o$...?
Am I missing something here?
My brain is still hazy from the long break, so maybe I'm confusing simple things here ;)

Comment: You should never accept an answer that fast. Wait for other answers, maybe hours or days. Perhaps you are missing out on a more detailed answer...

Comment: Ha, undid it, thanks for the advice :)

Comment: It is however a good practice to +1 an answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

**The Big Omega notation**

The definition of the Big Omega $\Omega$ notation may cause confusion. Quoting Wikipedia:

> Unfortunately, there are two widespread and incompatible definitions of the statement
> $$f(x)=\Omega(g(x))\quad (x\rightarrow a),$$
> where $a$ is some real number, $∞$, or $−∞$, where $f$ and $g$ are real functions defined in a neighbourhood of $a$, and where $g$ is positive in this neighbourhood.
> The first one (chronologically) is used in analytic number theory, and the other one in computational complexity theory. When the two subjects meet, this situation is bound to generate confusion.

*The Hardy–Littlewood definition*

In 1914 Godfrey Harold Hardy and John Edensor Littlewood introduced the new symbol $\Omega$, which is defined as follows

$$f(x)=\Omega(g(x))\ (x\rightarrow\infty)\;\iff\;\limsup_{x \to \infty} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|> 0$$

*The Knuth definition*

In 1976 Donald Knuth published a paper to justify his use of the $\Omega$-symbol to describe a stronger property. Knuth wrote: "For all the applications I have seen so far in computer science, a stronger requirement ... is much more appropriate". He defined $f(x)=\Omega(g(x))\Leftrightarrow g(x)=O(f(x))$, in other words
$$f(x)=\Omega(g(x))\ (x\rightarrow\infty)\;\iff\;\liminf_{x \to \infty} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|> 0.$$

**Difference between the Big O notation and the Big Omega notation**

Since you stated that this exercise is an assignment in algorithms we will use the Knuth definition of $\Omega$. Let's look at the definitions again:

$$f=O(g) \iff \limsup_{x \to \infty} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right| < \infty, \qquad f=\Omega(g)\;\iff\;\liminf_{x \to \infty} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|> 0$$

We have three major differences here.

1. Big $O$ is defined as a limit superior, whereas Big $\Omega$ is defined as a limit inferior.
2. The limit in the Big $O$ definition can be equal to zero, whereas the limit in the $\Omega$ definition has to be strictly greater than zero.
3. The limit in the $\Omega$ notation is allowed to go to $+\infty$.

So if $f= O(g)$, $|f|$ is asymptotically bounded above by $g$ and if $f=\Omega(g)$, $\lvert f\rvert$ is asymptotically bounded below by $g$.

If we look at the definition with quantifiers, we can also see how these definitions differ,
$$
\begin{align}
f&=O(g) \iff \exists\ c > 0\ \exists\ x_0 > 0\ \forall\ x > x_0: |f(x)| \le c\cdot|g(x)|,\\ \qquad f&=\Omega(g) \iff \exists\ c > 0\ \exists\ x_0 > 0\ \forall\ x > x_0: c\cdot \lvert g(x)\rvert\le|f(x)|.
\end{align}
$$

**The limit and l'hopital**

Let's look at the limit first. By l'hopital the solution is indeed $1$,

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+\pi}{n-e^{2021}}= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n}(n+\pi)}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n}(n-e^{2021})}  = \frac{1}{1} = 1.$$

One important condition which has to be satisfied if applying l'hopitals rule on $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)/g(x)$ is that $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)/g'(x)$ must exist. From this it follows that you cannot apply l'hopital on $1/1$, since $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n}(1)/\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n}(1)=0/0$ does not exist.

Now we can safely state that

$$n+\pi=\Omega(n-e^{2021})$$

and that

$$n+\pi \neq o(n-e^{2021}).$$

Here $\neq$ is being used loosely. Remark: By definition, if a function is in $\Omega$ it cannot be in $o$.

We may also say that $n+\pi = O(n-e^{2021})$ and the sharper statement $n+\pi \sim n-e^{2021}$, which is equivalent to the limit you evaluated earlier.

Comment: Possible typo? In quantifiered definition of $\Omega$ should be existence with $x_0$ and forall with $x$.

Comment: No it's correct. This is the unfortunate confusion with the Hardy-Littlewood and the Knuth definition. You are taking about the latter one, whereas I wrote that $\Omega$ is used in the Hardy-Littlewood definition. Furthermore the Knuth $\Omega$ is defined as a limit inferior and the Hardy-Littlewood $\Omega$ is defined as a limit superior.

Comment: Do you mean case when Hardy-Littlewood define $\Omega$ as negation of little-$o$ in their paper on 225 page? If yes, then, I think, OP hardly means it, as wrote about first assignment in algorithms, though, anyway, it's good dig in history.

Comment: @zkutch Thanks I overread that it was an assignment in algorithms. I saw the limit $(n+\pi)/(n+e^{2021})$ and this was an indicator for me that it is a problem from number theory/analysis and not from algorithms because of the choice of the constants.

Comment: By [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations), it uses def_1: $\exists k>0\,\forall n_{0}\,\exists n>n_{0}\colon |f(n)|\geq k\,g(n)$ for the Hardy-Littlewood definition. If someone has questions about why it is equivalent with def_2: $\limsup _{n\to \infty }{\frac {\left|f(n)\right|}{g(n)}}>0$, I share my thoughts here. Please point out errors if any. Thanks beforehand. ($\limsup$ [calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2304847/1059606))

Comment: Here wikipedia assumes [$g(x)>0,x\to \infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition). 1. def_1->def_2: since the main body is $\exists n>n_{0},\frac{|f(n)|}{|g(n)|}\ge k$, so it can't ensure $\forall n>n_{0} \ldots$, then not $\liminf$. But $\sup \frac{|f(n)|}{|g(n)|}$ is greater than or equal to all possible $\frac{|f(n)|}{|g(n)|}$, so $\sup \frac{|f(n)|}{|g(n)|}\ge \frac{|f(n)|}{|g(n)|}\ge k>0$. Then take the limit by the above calculation link.

Comment: 2. Take the nearest possible value of $\frac{|f(n)|}{|g(n)|}$ where $n$ meets the requirement $\forall n_{0}\,\exists n>n_{0}$ (i.e. $n$ can be seen almost as $\infty$), let it be $m$. Then $m>0$ by the sup definition. Then we can let $k=m>0$.

Answer (score 2):

1. For first: using for big-$\mathrm{O}$ $\boldsymbol{\lim \sup}$ gives more clear and right understanding, only limit can not work here, as you correctly doubt.

Let me add, also, that ratio form is not most general form for asymptotic definitions. For example, when we use in definitions of type $\frac{f}{g}$, then we lost cases for such $g$, which can have zero values. So, if we take definition without limits, then it's clear from scratch, that big-$\mathrm{O}$ gives boundedness for $f$ from **above**, by a constant multiple of $g$, while big-$\Omega$ gives boundedness for $f$ from **below**, by a constant multiple of $g$.

2. For second question: you can use  l'Hopital* in certain conditions, $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, but at last step you have not this.

Application of l'Hopital sometimes meet more subtle mistakes, because conditions of theorem rarely checked. Most times people use l'Hopital without thinking about theorem's conditions: when see $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ they immediately shoot from l'Hopital rifle, which can be dangerous. For example, should exists limit for $\frac{f'}{g'}$. If you take $\frac{x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}}{\sin x}$, when $x \to 0$, then it is not possible to use l'Hopital by mentioned reason. Also l'Hopital required $f'^2+g'^2\ne 0$, or $g' \ne 0$, in  limit point some neighbourhood. If we take $\frac{x-\sin x }{x+\sin x }$ when $x \to \infty$, then again is not possible to use l'Hopital.

$\ast ~$ L'Hopital is also spelled l'Hospital (from old french) or l'Hôpital (modern french).

Comment: to be entirely rigourous we check for the absolute values in the boundedness

Comment: Of course. In general spaces is used norm and in computer science mostly are using non negative functions, but here, as I think, we deal with understanding of definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's restate l’Hôpital's Rule

> Let $a,b$ be two real numbers such that $a<b$. Let $\ell$ be a real number or $\pm \infty$.
>
> Let $\displaystyle f$ and ${\displaystyle g}$  two differentiable functions ${\displaystyle \left]a,b\right[}$ such that ${\displaystyle g'\neq 0}$
>
> 1. if $\displaystyle \lim_a f(x)=\lim_a  g(x)=0$ & $\displaystyle\lim_{a^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\ell $ then $\displaystyle\lim_{a^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\ell $
> 2. If $\displaystyle \lim_a f(x)=\lim_a  g(x)=+\infty$ & $\displaystyle\lim_{a^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\ell $ then $\displaystyle\lim_{a^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\ell $

The problem is you can only apply l'Hôpital if you get an indeterminate form which is not the case of $\frac11$

Your result is therefore correct it is big $\Omega$.

Note that when the fraction is equal to one we often say that $f$ is equivalent to $g$ noted $f \sim g$

Here you don't even need to use l'Hôpital to conclude : just factor both the numerator and denominator by $n$.

Now when it comes to the notation :

A picky note first, all these letter are greek including the big-Oh ($\text{Omicron}$) therefore, one should note $\text{O}$ and not $O$ but thats neatpicking

Note that most often we consider positive-valued function, therefore you may ignore the $|\cdot|$ in what follows.

What $f=\text{O}(g)$ means is that $|f|$ is bounded above by some constant multiple of $|g|$ that is    from a certain value $N$ on, we can find a positive **constant** $c$ such that
$$|f(n)| \leq |g(n)|\cdot c$$

or for quantifier boys out there
$$f=\text{O}(g)\iff \exists c\in\mathbb{R}_+^*, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N},n>N\implies|f(n)| \leq |g(n)|\cdot c$$

$\Omega$ means the reverse condition holds* , that is
$$f=\Omega(g)\iff \exists c\in\mathbb{R}_+^*, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N},n>N\implies|g(n)|\cdot c \leq |f(n)|$$

We can in fact say: $$f=\text{O}(g) \iff g=\Omega(f)$$

* not exactly the logic negation but that's the idea

Comment: The OP did not apply l'hopital on $1/1$.

Comment: When op says <<but if I do l'Hopital again, it comes down to zero>>, I think he means just this.

Comment: OP said he evaluated the limit with l'hopital and got the result $1/1$. Everything's correct. Applying l'hopital again is not correct, which you stated right.

Comment: okay, thanks for clarifying! So only use l'Hopital when it is inf/inf or 0/0?

Comment: Yes the rationale is that if your function goes crazy, the fastest one wins and the speed is exactly what the derivative measures