# What does big Omega imply about big O? And how does $f(n)=\Omega(n)$ imply cannot be bounded by a constant?

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to figure out the implications of $\Omega$ in asymptotic analysis.  Let's say I have a function $f(n)=\Omega(n)$.  From my understanding, and [Asymptotic analysis: difference between big O and big Omega limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4124155/)

this implies the following:

$\exists c>0$, such that $\exists n_0 $ s.t. $\forall n \ge n_0, \,\, f(n) \ge cn$

In some literature, I've heard this described as "f(n) cannot be bounded by a constant". I'd like to know why that is the case.  To *me* $f(n)=\Omega(n)$ seems to imply the following:

$\nexists c >0$, such that $\exists n_0 $ s.t. $\forall n \ge n_0, \,\, f(n) < cn$.

...which to me means its performance cannot be bounded by a linear function of $n$.  i.e. $O(n) < f(n)$.   How does this imply $f(n)$ cannot be bounded by a constant?  Can't we say something stronger?

Comment: The table [Family of Bachmann–Landau notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) has the correct definitions. The first statement you write is correct (and the second incorrect). The answer to your question is your second statement is not correct. $f \in \Omega(n)$ is not the same as saying $f$ cannot be bounded above by a constant (though it does imply this). For instance, $\log(n)$ cannot be bounded above by a constant but is not in $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: I think you're getting tripped up by your specific choice of a linear function rather than the more general g(n) cases shown in the tables GeoffreySangston linked.  You're looking to prove whether you can find an example constant (maybe call it a "constant multiplier") $c$ satisfying $f(n)\geq c\cdot g(n)$, not specifically whether one can satisfy $f(n)\geq c$ (regardless of $g(n)$).

Comment: Very sorry guys - I made a big typo.  The second statement was supposed to be *not exists*.  It is fixed now, hopefully the question makes more sense.

@GeoffreySangston, that's my confusion exactly.  Why not say something stronger:  Doesn't $f(n) \in \Omega(n)$ imply that $f(n)$ cannot be bounded by $O(n))$, and hence also cannot be bounded by $O(log(n))$, and cannot be bounded by $O(1)$?  It seems like we can make a stronger statement.

Comment: @somewhere $f \in \Omega(n)$ does not imply $f$ cannot be bounded above by $O(n)$. For instance, $n \in \Omega(n)$. A less trivial example is $n^2/(n+1) \in \Omega(n)$. Both of these functions are also in $O(n)$; i.e. $\Theta(n) := \Omega(n) \cap O(n)$ is a non-empty set. It is true that $f \in \omega(n)$ implies $f \notin O(n)$ (see table... also the equivalent limit definitions on the right may be helpful). And it is true that $f \in \Omega(n)$ implies $f \notin O(\log(n))$.

I don't know how to answer why someone would or wouldn't say something stronger. Perhaps it was unnecessary.